# Luis Cognitive Services DateTime Entity

Tags: azure-cognitive-services, azure-language-understanding

I'm having date time formatting issues with the Luis Service and using the builtin.datetime entity.

Being in the UK, it is natural for users to enter a date in the dd-mm-yyyy format. However, this causes issues as Luis does not recognise a date such as 13-04-2017 as a datetime entity. It happily recognises 12-04-2017, but then the 'resolution' of the field is 2017-12-04. This makes it very difficult to use the field. Luis doesn't even recognise 12 April 2017 as a date.

Has anyone else encountered this issue and been able to come up with a suitable workaround? Other than getting our users to enter in mm/dd/yyyy format.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortuantely, currently this model is trained only for en-US; it's something we want to improve going forward and have on our roadmap.

Thanks